# Fatal error Call to a member function prepare() on null

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to check if email was already used in Registration. It worked well when I was working on it in the school but now it suddenly shows an error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null

I use this to include

```
define("dbserver", "localhost");
define("dbuser", "user");
define("dbpass", "");
define("dbname", "user");    


$db = new PDO(
"mysql:host=" .dbserver. ";dbname=" .dbname,dbuser,
array(
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8",
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET CHARACTER SET utf8"
) );
```

In here

```
session_start();
include "DBjoin.php";
if(isset($_POST["email"])) {
  $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST["email"];
  }   
if(isset($_POST["nick"])) {
  $_SESSION['nick'] = $_POST["nick"];         
}    
if(isset($_POST["pass"])) {
  $_SESSION['pass'] = $_POST["pass"];
  $_SESSION['pass'] = base64_encode($_SESSION['pass']);    
}
$sthandler = $db->prepare("SELECT Email FROM Registrace WHERE Email =     :email");
$sthandler->bindParam(':email', $_SESSION['email']);
$sthandler->execute();               
if(filter_var($_SESSION['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
if($sthandler->rowCount() > 0){
      echo "Email is used";}
```

Comment: Store $db in a global variable, try it

Comment: @KA_lin why not just through their function instead? global is often frowned upon. Plus, it's not used in a function, so no use for it.

Comment: Connection failed. Look for error messages

Comment: Add `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened. Plus, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Nota: If your connection parameters contains spaces, that will be an issue.

Comment: *"Call to a member function prepare() on null"* - this tells me that your query failed. Make sure your HTML form is using a POST method and that your inputs all hold the `name` attribute with no typos etc. Include your HTML form in your question to leave the guesswork out of it. Also check your table and column names; there might be a letter-case issue also. On certain systems, `Email` and `email` are not considered the same.

Comment: and technically speaking, you're missing a closing brace for `if(filter_var($_SESSION['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {` in your question. So, how about some feedback now?

Comment: @Fred-ii not `query`, but the connection. `prepare` was called for the connection before query was there :)

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky you're right; it's definitely their connection.

Comment: Any idea what is wrong with it? It worked before so there must be some minor issue I am missing...

Comment: Use some basic error checking from PDO Manual that will tell you the exact error

Comment: might be because of the constants. try the standard method as per the manual http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php

Comment: @Mark I figured out the problem. Please reload the answer I have provided below, since it has been edited in order to reflect the reason why it is failing.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky I figured it out; missing password parameter. *quick update* ;-) I knew it had to be something "missing".

Comment: Fred the second rocks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** (I figured it out).

I finally figured out why your code is not working and my original answer no longer applies, which I have stricken out.

The reason why your connection does not work, is because you left out the `dbpass` constant from the connection parameter.

```
$db = new PDO(
"mysql:host=" .dbserver. ";dbname=" .dbname,dbuser,dbpass,
array(
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8",
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET CHARACTER SET utf8"
) );
```

- Even though you may not have a password set for it, it is still required to be part of the parameters.
- http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php

---

Original answer, which no longer applies. (see edit above).

<strike>TBH, I wasn't able to reproduce the error, amidst a great effort.</strike>

However; after tinkering with this, have discovered that PDO (*least, the one on my server*), won't allow for [**constants**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) be used as the first 2 parameters in the DSN.

*Sidenote:* If what you say worked at your school, then there may be a setting used that I don't know about.

You can however, assign variables to the constants, then use those variables in the DSN.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$dbname = "user";

define("dbuser", "user");
define("dbpass", "");

$dsn = "mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname";

$username = dbuser; // variable equals constant
$password = dbpass; // variable equals constant

$options = array(
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8",
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET CHARACTER SET utf8"
); 

$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
```

For more information on PDO connection, visit:

- http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: You should use try/catch statement for PDOException, it will point you right away that the password is wrong, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36287723/591257