# Error in my User.php file when learning Simple PDO login system

Tags: php, pdo

Please,am learning how to code a simple PDO login system. One of my files, that is User.php has an error after rendering.

This is my code:

```
<?php

include_once('connection.php');
class User{

private $db;
public function _construct(){

$this->db = new Connection();
$this->db = $this->db->dbConnect();
}
public function login($name,$pass){

if(!empty($name) && !empty($pass)){

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare(" SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = ? and pass = ? ");
    $stmt -> bindParam(1,$name);
    $stmt -> bindParam(2,$pass);
    $stmt -> execute();

    if($stmt->rowCount()==1){
        echo "successfully login";
    }else{
        echo "incorrect username or password";
    }
    } else{
        echo "enter correct username and password";
    }
```

Here is the error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\simplelogin\User.php on line 16

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error Call to a member function prepare() on null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627027/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-prepare-on-null)

Answer (score 0):

This means `$this->db` is `null` and has not been initialized.

Change this line:
`public function _construct(){`

To:

`public function __construct(){`

You are missing an underscore in the [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#object.construct). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @ Osama.Please will like to know how to hash the password

Comment: @Emmanuel You can use password_hash() function http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php To hash your password `$hashedPassword = password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);` and you can use password_verify function http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php to verify the password against its hashed value. Check this example here http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php#refsect1-function.password-verify-examples. Hope this help.

Comment: Man,my problem i dont understand the code.Aside,finding it difficult how to insert it in my code.