# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting this error in my PHP file.

My login function

```
<?php
session_start();
include ("../dbConnection.php");


class login {

    public $link;

    function __construct()
    {
        $dbc = new dbConnection();
        $this->link = $dbc->Connect();
        return $this->link;
    }

    public function get_data($emailid,$password)
    {
        $q = $this->link->prepare("SELECT id from students WHERE emailid='$emailid' AND password='$password' AND active='Yes'");
        $q->execute(array(':emailid'=>$emailid,':password'=>$password));
        $counts = $q->fetch();
        if($counts['id'] > 0)
        {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['userlogin'] = $counts['id'];
            $encrypt_id1 = $this->encrypt_decrypt('encrypt', $counts['id']);
            echo $encrypt_id1;
        }            
    }
}
```

dbConnection.php

```
<?php

public class dbConnection {

    public $conn;


    public $db_host = 'localhost';
    public $db_name = 'pte_mock';
    public $db_user = 'root';
    public $db_pass = '';

    public function Connect()
    {
        try{
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->db_host.";dbname=".$this->db_name,$this->db_user,$this->db_pass);
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }    
        return $this->conn;
    }
}
```

I'm getting error with below statement

```
"$q = $this->link->prepare("SELECT id from students WHERE emailid='$emailid' AND password='$password' AND active='Yes'");"
```

Error

```
"PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null"
```

I don't know whats the issue with this.If anyone knows solution please help me to get out of this issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28592400/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-prepare-on-null)

Comment: A constructor in php must never return anything!

Comment: I tried that but its not solved my issue.

Comment: that ain't a prepared statement, you just injected variables directly in your sql statement, its like using a crowbar to pound a nail

Comment: @arkascha Can you please advocate your comment?

Comment: So what shall I do with the issue??

Comment: @BhavikShah What is there to elaborate? Constructors do not explicitly return anything. The above code tries to return something. That does not make sense.

Comment: So If I remove that constructor is that okie.

Comment: No, you do _not_ remove the constructor! Not sure if that `return` statement causes an issue here, this might be independent from your current issue. It is just a general remark.

Comment: I got this error from http sever error log file only.

Comment: Strange... Check what $this->link holds at the end of that constructor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146830/discussion-between-kavya-shree-and-arkascha).

Comment: you need to change your connection details . as per hosted server right now .

Comment: The username and password is given as per hosted server ly

Comment: I've spotted some major issues on the code you posted. You may try to fix them with the hints on my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi .. Have you fixed this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44667690/disable-fast-forward-audio-in-audio-js/ check out this

Answer (score 0):

When you define a **class** you **do need** a constructor in order to initialize instance variables.

```
class dbConnection {

    public $conn,

           $db_host,
           $db_name,
           $db_user,
           $db_pass;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->conn = false;

        $this->db_host = 'localhost';
        $this->db_name = 'pte_mock';
        $this->db_user = 'root';
        $this->db_pass = '';
    }

    /* ... */
```

Also a class cannot be defined `public`, that should raise a syntax error at compile time.

So you just have `class dbConnection {`

---

I'm not sure this is leading to problems but construstors **must not** return values. In fact they return **the instance (object) just created**.

You have into the class `login`:

```
function __construct()
{
    $dbc = new dbConnection();
    $this->link = $dbc->Connect();
    // return $this->link;  // <--- REMOVE THAT - YOU CANNOT RETURN VALUES HERE!
}
```

When you call `$lgn = new login()` the function `__construct()` is invoked and you get into `$lgn` a new instance of the class `login`. If the constructor returns anything that is discarded!

So you should refactor your code this way:

```
$lgn = new login(); // <--- returns a new instance of the class login
$the_link= $lgn->link; // <--- this way you access `link` instance variable
```

---

Finally this

```
    $q = $this->link->prepare("SELECT id from students WHERE emailid='$emailid' AND password='$password' AND active='Yes'");
```

Is not the proper way to build a prepared statement as you're injecting values into the query instead of specifying placeholders.

The line should be written this way

```
    $q = $this->link->prepare("SELECT id from students WHERE emailid=:$emailid AND password=:password AND active='Yes'");
```

Answer (score -1):

replace this part of your code

```
$q = $this->link->prepare("SELECT id from students WHERE emailid='$emailid' AND password='$password' AND active='Yes'");

$q->execute(array(':emailid'=>$emailid,':password'=>$password));
```

with this:

```
$q = $this->link->prepare("SELECT id FROM students WHERE emailid = :emailid AND password = :password AND active = 'Yes'");

$q->execute(array(':emailid'=>$emailid,':password'=>$password));
```

Comment: not from me the downvote. However the issue you pointed out is just one of many and not the one that breaks the code.