# Disable fast forward audio in audio.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, html5-audio

Hi everyone,

I had used https://kolber.github.io/audiojs/ plugin for my application.There is a option to forward audio like using mouse I can forward audio.I want to disable the forward in user interface using jquery or css.

I tried searching in many ways.Please anyone help me to get out this issue.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't seem like they have any official documentation for the Library.

One hack you can apply is unbinding the event on the player progress bar.

```
$('scrubber').unbind('click'); // Not passing click will unbind all events.
```

This way user won't be able to click the progress and forward it.

I wouldn't recommend it, but more suitable way would be using proper Api if provided by the library.

Comment: After adding this also I can forward audio