# PHP not sending data to phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

I’m creating a website, and want to send data to MySQL, but it doesn't send.

I can give more details if needed.

Full code https://pastebin.com/JW5UUQbt

```
if(isset($_POST['submit2']))
{
$pid=intval($_GET['pkgid']);
$useremail=$_SESSION['login'];
$date=$_POST['date'];
$time=$_POST['time'];
$comment=$_POST['comment'];
$status=0;
$sql="INSERT INTO tblbooking (PackageId, UserEmail, BDate, BTime, Comment, status) VALUES (:pid, :useremail , :bdate , :btime , :comment , :status);";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':pid',$pid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':useremail',$useremail,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':bdate',$date,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':btime',$time,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':comment',$comment,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':status',$status,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
?>
<form name="book" method="post">
                <label class="inputLabel">Date</label>
                <input type="text" name="date" required="">
            <div class="bnr-right">
                <label class="inputLabel">Time</label>
                <input type="text" name="time" required="">
            </div>
                        <label class="inputLabel">Comment</label>
                        <input class="special" type="text" name="comment">
                    </li>
                    <?php if($_SESSION['login'])
                    {?>
                        <li class="spe" align="center">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit2" class="btn-primary btn">Book</button>
                        </li>
                        <?php } else {?>
                            <li class="sigi" align="center" style="margin-top: 1%">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal4" class="btn-primary btn" > Book</a></li>
                            <?php } ?>
            </div>

        </div>
        </form>
<?php }} ?>
```

Comment: The logs are your friend. They will typically tell you what isn't working and exactly where. Otherwise we are just wasting time with conjecture. What isn't working specifically?

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a MySQL administration tool written in PHP, it is not a database itself. You are probably using MySQL or MariaDB as your DB.

Comment: After submit data not reaching database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My PDO Statement doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32648371/my-pdo-statement-doesnt-work)

Comment: You may try a system of debugging computer software known as rubber duck debugging https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Comment: Have you run some basic debugging, check the variables you are using e.g.: `echo $pid;`, `echo $useremail;`, `echo $date;`, `echo $time;`, `echo $comment;` see what they contain?

Comment: Yes , http://prntscr.com/o75ef8

Comment: The `print_r($dbh->errorInfo());` shows `Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified the code a bit (including hard coding the values for $useremail and $pid) to identify what could be causing the problem, and it worked first time around:

```
<?php 
  // DB credentials.
  define('DB_HOST','localhost');
  define('DB_USER','root');
  define('DB_PASS','');
  define('DB_NAME','test');
  // Establish database connection.
 try
  {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";port=3307;dbname=".DB_NAME,DB_USER, DB_PASS,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
  }
 catch (PDOException $e)
  {
      exit("Error: " . $e->getMessage());  
   }
?>

<?php

 if(isset($_POST['submit2']))
  {
    $pid=6;
    $useremail= "hello@domain.com";
    $date=$_POST['date'];
    $time=$_POST['time'];
    $comment=$_POST['comment'];
    $status=0;
    $sql="INSERT INTO tblbooking (PackageId, UserEmail, BDate, BTime, Comment, status) VALUES (:pid, :useremail , :bdate , :btime , :comment , :status);";
    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':pid',$pid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':useremail',$useremail,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':bdate',$date,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':btime',$time,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':comment',$comment,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':status',$status,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
  }
?>

<form name="book" method="post">
     <label class="inputLabel">Date</label>
     <input type="text" name="date" required="">
     <div class="bnr-right">
        <label class="inputLabel">Time</label>
        <input type="text" name="time" required="">
     </div>
     <label class="inputLabel">Comment</label>
     <input class="special" type="text" name="comment">
      <button type="submit" name="submit2" class="btn-primary btn">Book</button>          
 </form>
```

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in X:\OSPanel\domains\kajaki2.com\package-details.php:12 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in X:\OSPanel\domains\kajaki2.com\package-details.php on line 12` tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28592400/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-prepare-on-null but doesn't work

Comment: I have edited the code to include the db connection details, I used, the only difference from code in the pastebin is the db name - test, and I included a port number in the connection as I have more than one MySQL running locally.

Comment: And still issues remain

Comment: What issues are you having?

Comment: Values didn't appear in db

Comment: Check that you are using the correct database and table names

Comment: http://prntscr.com/o76h4q how my db looks

Comment: Nothing is being inserted into UserNumber column in the query, and it is set to NOT NULL, hence a value should be inserted or change it to NULL

Comment: Removing UserNumber column fixed , what the stupid mistake

Comment: It happens to everyone :)