# Laravel and MongoDB gives error Call to a member function prepare() on null

Tags: laravel, mongodb

I tried to reach the web page but i get Call to a member function prepare().
what i should to do ?
I'm using laravel and MongoDB.
all codes worked good but i get above error when i updated Laravel from 5.8 to 6

`<!-- Authentication Links -->
                @guest
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                    </li>
                    @if (Route::has('register'))
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                        </li>
                    @endif
                @else
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                            {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                               onclick="event.preventDefault();
                               document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                {{ __('Logout') }}
                            </a>
                            <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                @csrf
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                @endguest`

problem is about @guest

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28592400/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-prepare-on-null) Take a look at this question, it may help you to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

in "vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User.php"

add "use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;"

change the "class User extends Model implements" to "class User extends Eloquent implements"

Answer (score 0):

in each model use add:
"use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;"
and after you should extend from this eloquent instead extend Model

Answer (score 0):

I've found an alternative fix.

in `vendor\spatie\laravel-permission\src\Models\Permission.php` and `\Role.php`

set this:

```
<?php

...
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
...

class Permission extends Authenticatable implements PermissionContract
{
```

I hope it helps you ;)