# update profile picture but kept getting this Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null

Tags: php, mysql, function, oop

Trying to update my admin profile image but kept getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null

```
class Admin
{
    public function UPDATE_ADMIN_IMAGE($imagelocation, $id) {
        global $db;

        $sql = "UPDATE admin
                SET imglocation = ?
                WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1";
        if(!$stmt = $db->prepare($sql)) {
            echo $stmt->error;
        } else {
            $stmt->bind_param("si", $imagelocation, $id);       
        }

        if($stmt->execute()) {
            echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>image was uploaded successfully.</div>";

        }else{
            echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>image was not uploaded successfully.</div>";
        }
        $stmt->free_result();
        return $stmt;
    }
}
```

This is where the a new object is created

```
<?php


            if(isset($_POST['updateimg'])) {
              $id = $_POST['id'];
              $path = 'uploads/';
              $npath = 'admin/uploads/';
              $name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
              $size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];
              $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];


              $newpath = $path.$name;
              move_uploaded_file($tmp, $newpath);
              $imagelocation = $newpath;

              $adminimg = new Admin();
              $addimgadmin = $adminimg->UPDATE_ADMIN_IMAGE($imagelocation, $id);
            }
              ?>
```

Comment: From where are you calling the function UPDATE_ADMIN_IMAGE() and also show us the defined parameters passed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28592400/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-prepare-on-null)

Comment: it means $db is either not initialised or the initialisation process failed for some reason. In this case it looks like the reason is probably the first one (not initialised) If you trace your script back to the opening `<?php` before you call `$adminimg->UPDATE_ADMIN_IMAGE` there is no sign of any code which would cause `$db` to be created. P.S. global variables are really an obsolete pattern these days, if you really want to share your connection object around then use the Singleton Pattern or something like that. Then you have a traceable path to show you've set it up correctly before use.

Answer (score 0):

As ADyson mentioned, `$db` is `null`.

Consider separating concerns on your ADMIN class by requiring methods to pass a reference to the $db, e.g.

```
public function UPDATE_ADMIN_IMAGE(&$db, $imagelocation, $id)
```

This can help you track down why $db is null and also eliminate the reliance on such a global which has proved problematic.